# MySQL left outer join returning NULL values

Tags: mysql

for reasons I can't explain, a left outer join, which used to work fine, no longer works after a modification of one of the tables.

The code is pretty choppy up to this point, as it involves a lot of previous joins, but at the point where I'm stuck, it's simply seeking to join where two values match:

```
mysql_query ("CREATE TABLE Everything(
SELECT * from two
    left outer join CPEs on CPEs.cpe_cust_index = two.cust_index2
    where cust_index2 > \"0\"
)")
or die (mysql_error());#("this certainly didn't work\n");
 echo "It works!\n";'
```

This used to match up the two fields (both varchars of the same length) and append CPEs to two, but now the table Everything displays NULL wherever the fields from CPEs should be.

Am I missing something obvious?

All I can think of is that two.cust_index2 is no longer a unique field (though CPEs.cpe_cust_index is unique), but that shouldn't matter.

The fields are simple numbers, and there are definite matches (from observation)

Comment: Please post a small data sample from both tables.

Comment: Also, it is not recommended to `SELECT *` in a join query. Always be explicit with the columns in your `SELECT` list, as they won't be returned properly if the joined tables have name collisions.

Comment: Can you post the table definitions? Slight concern that you state that the fields are just numbers, yet you are putting quotes around the cust_index2 value in the WHERE clause. If two.cust_index2 was no longer unique then you would just get multiple rows returned.

Answer (score 0):

@Michael, You've solved it, in a roundabout way.  When I exported a CSV file, I noticed a preceding space in front of each field of the old table.  I've just edited my scripts to sort and remove the spaces, and it works now.

Annoying, as I would have seen a trailing space, but the tool I'm using seems to subtract a preceding space when I view it.

Thanks for your time guys!